# "No operator '=' matches these operands" error with Ogre::Vector3

Tags: vector, ogre

I'm having issue with initialising a vector in one of my derived classes. I'm using OGRE and want to initialise a position in a derived class called CMissile.

CMissile inherits from CWeapon (which has one pure virtual function).

CWeapon.h:

```
#include "CPlayer.h"

class CWeapon
{
protected:
    CPlayer& myOwner; //Reference to player
    Ogre::Vector3 myPosition;

public:
    CPlayer getOwner();
    virtual void doBehaviour() = 0; //Do not add method body for this in CWeapon.cpp, pure virtual function
};
```

CMissile.h:

```
#include "CWeapon.h"

class CMissile : CWeapon
{
private:
    float myDirection;

public:
    CMissile(float, float, float, float, CPlayer&);
};
```

and here in CMissile.cpp is where my error resides:

```
#include "CMissile.h"

CMissile::CMissile(float x, float y, float z, float dir, CPlayer& player)
{
    this->myOwner = player;
    this->myDirection = dir;
    this->myPosition = new Ogre::Vector3(x, y, z); //here is the error, which reads "No operator '=' matches these operands"
}
```

In CPlayer.h (included in CWeapon) I have the line:

```
#include <OgreVector3.h>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be because Ogre::Vector3 myPosition; is protected?

Comment: Also note that this->myOwner=player; will NOT change what mOwner is referring to, but instead overwrite whatever it was pointing to (nothing?!) with the contents of "player". No idea why you do not get a compile error for not initializing it - did you leave that out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new Ogre::Vector3` will allocate a new vector on the heap (resulting in a `Ogre::Vector3 *`, a pointer to that vector). You are trying to assign it to `myPosition`, which is simply of type `Ogre::Vector3`. Those two types are not compatible.

You probably don't want to use `new` at all here, and instead do:

```
this->myPosition = Ogre::Vector3(x, y, z);
```

(which will assign a temporary vector to `myPosition`) or just directly update the position via:

```
this->myPosition.x = x;
this->myPosition.y = y;
this->myPosition.z = z;
```

Comment: Ahh, I've been working with JMonkey all week up until now, and am in the habit of having to initialise vectors as new objects before using them.